# Why does Excel MATCH() not find a match?

Tags: excel, excel-match

I have a table with some numbers stored as text (UPC codes, so I don't want to lose leading zeros). `COUNTIF()` recognizes matches just fine, but `MATCH()` doesn't work. Is there a reason why `MATCH()` can't handle numbers stored as text, or is this just a limitation I'll have to work around?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Functions like `MATCH`, `VLOOKUP` and `HLOOKUP` need to match data type (number or text) whereas `COUNTIF/SUMIF` make no distinction. Are you using MATCH to find the position or just to establish whether the value exists in your data?

If you have a numeric lookup value you can convert to text in the formula by using &"", e.g.

`=MATCH(A1&"",B:B,0)`

....or if it's a text lookup value which needs to match with numbers

`=MATCH(A1+0,B:B,0)`

Comment: What barry says is correct but I would favour the more expressive `=MATCH(TEXT(A1,"0"),B:B,0)` or `=MATCH(VALUE(A1),B:B,0)`

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: @barry Hey you are my GOD! `Functions like MATCH, VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP need to match data type  whereas COUNTIF/SUMIF make no distinction` is oracle!

Comment: Note also that you can apply the transform to both sides, if you have no idea what the format is: `=MATCH(VALUE(A1), VALUE(B:B), 0)` works well for me.

Comment: Using `=MATCH(A1+0,B:B,0)` helped me out. This works across tables as well, like `=MATCH(My_Table[[#data],[Column_Name]]+0,[@[Value]],0)'`

Comment: @JustinJDavies `TEXT` distorts the value (e.g. in your example, it'll print `1` if the value is `0.5`; if I change the format to `"0,0"`, it prints `1000,0` if the value is `1e3`). So it's not a reliable conversion function -- while barry's method is reliable.

Comment: @JustinJDavies Likewise, `VALUE` returns an error if the value is not a number. Not reliable, either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the word test for example in cell A2, type the following:

**=MATCH("*"&"test"&"*",A2,0)**

If this isn't working then try **=Trim** and **=Clean** to purify your column.

If =Trim and =Clean don't help, then just use the left 250 characters... 
(As the Match Formula may encounter a timeout/overflow after 250 characters.)

**=Left(A2, 250)**

Answer (score -1):

If you are using names to refer to the ranges, once you have fixed the datatypes also redefine any names which refer to those ranges.